# Error with DeadLetters and ActorRef

Tags: scala, akka

I encounter an error while running my project I cannot solve.

Here is my code:

```
import akka.actor._
import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.actor.Props
import akka.actor.ScalaActorRef
import akka.pattern.gracefulStop
import akka.util._
import java.util.Calendar
import java.util.concurrent._
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import scala.Array._
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

sealed trait Message
case class ReturnInfluenceMessage(source: ActorRef) extends Message
case class SetInfluences(source: ActorRef) extends Message
case class GetInfluence() extends Message

class Listener extends Actor {
    def receive = {
        case ReturnInfluenceMessage(s0urce) => println ("Listener: received influence (" +     s0urce + ")")
    }
}

class Entity extends Actor {
    val Influences = context.actorOf(Props[Influences], name = "Influences")
    def receive = {
        case SetInfluences(s0urce) => context.children foreach     (_.forward(SetInfluences(s0urce)))
        case GetInfluence => context.children foreach (_.forward(GetInfluence))
        case ReturnInfluenceMessage(source) =>
            source ! ReturnInfluenceMessage(source)
    }
}

class Influences extends Actor {
    private var source: ActorRef = _
    def receive = {
        case SetInfluences(s0urce)  => 
            source = s0urce
            println ("Influences: received " + s0urce)
            println ("Influences: Influence set to " + source)
        case GetInfluence =>
            println ("Influences: influence sent to " + source)
            sender ! ReturnInfluenceMessage(source)
    }
}

object main extends App {
    val system = akka.actor.ActorSystem("mySystem")
    val Abel = system.actorOf(Props[Listener], name = "Listener")
    val Cain = system.actorOf(Props[Entity], name = "Entity")

    system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(1500 milliseconds, Cain, SetInfluences(Abel))
    system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(3000 milliseconds, Cain, GetInfluence)
}
```

Here the error:

```
 [INFO] [08/29/2014 15:39:08.330] [mySystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://mySystem
 /deadLetters] Message [ReturnInfluenceMessage] from Actor[akka://mySystem/user/Entity
 /Shadow/Influences#1407138271] to Actor[akka://mySystem/deadLetters] was not 
 delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted 
 with configuration settings
 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

I am trying to set the variable `source` of the `Cain` actor to have this last one send the `ActorRef` of `Abel` to which a message figuring the `source` variable and display it.
The error happens here:

```
source ! ReturnInfluenceMessage(source)
```

, and I do not know why it occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you schedule a message with

```
system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(...)
```

a sender of that message is `DeadLetters` which is what you are trying to send message to in

```
sender ! ReturnInfluenceMessage(source)
```

and it is also what error message says.

Comment: Ok, thank you for answering. I found a way round the problem by replacing `sender` by `context.parent`, easy one. But this does not solve the problem. Am I not allowed to reach the not-`DeadLetters` sender with `sender`?

Comment: Let me paraphrase my answer. `sender` is `DeadLetters` when processing a message which was sent using `system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(...)` which is what your code does.

Answer (score 2):

@Martynas is correct in that your `sender` ref will be the `DeadLetter` ref when your code is setup the way it is.  The main issue is that you send in a message from outside of the actor system (via the scheduler) and then when you use `forward`, you continue to propagate the fact that you don't have a sender down into the next actor.  You can remedy this by using a `tell (!)` instead of forward.  I have modified your code sample to show this (as well as some other changes described after the code sample):

```
import akka.actor._
import concurrent.duration._

sealed trait Message
case class ReturnInfluenceMessage(source: ActorRef) extends Message
case class SetInfluences(source: ActorRef) extends Message
case object GetInfluence extends Message

class Listener extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case ReturnInfluenceMessage(s0urce) => println(s"Listener: received influence ($s0urce)")
  }
}

class Entity extends Actor {
  val influences = context.actorOf(Props[Influences], name = "Influences")
  def receive = {
    case si @ SetInfluences(s0urce) => 
      influences ! si

    case GetInfluence => 
      influences ! GetInfluence

    case rim @ ReturnInfluenceMessage(source) =>
      source ! rim
  }
}

class Influences extends Actor {
  def receive = setInfluence

  def setInfluence:Receive = {
    case SetInfluences(s0urce)  => 
      println (s"Influences: received $s0urce")
      println (s"Influences: Influence set to $s0urce")    
      context.become(withSource(s0urce) orElse setInfluence)
  }

  def withSource(source:ActorRef):Receive = {
    case GetInfluence =>
      println (s"Influences: influence sent to $source")
      sender ! ReturnInfluenceMessage(source)      
  }    
}

object Main extends App {
  val system = akka.actor.ActorSystem("mySystem")
  val abel = system.actorOf(Props[Listener], name = "Listener")
  val cain = system.actorOf(Props[Entity], name = "Entity")

  import system.dispatcher
  system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(1500 milliseconds, cain, SetInfluences(abel))
  system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(3000 milliseconds, cain, GetInfluence)
}
```

When I ran this I did not get any deadletters.  Other changes include:

- Formatting (2 spaces for indents, correct casing for var/vals)
- Changed `GetInfluence` into a case object as it did not have any fields
- Used variable binding in the case statements to capture a ref to the message (via the `@` symbol) when we needed to send that message along
- Used a two state setup for the `Influences` actor where it is first waiting for the state to be set (the `source` ref) and then switches to a state where it is able to respond properly to a `GetInfluences` message.  Probably want to explicitly handle a `GetInfluences` message when in the initial state as for now it's just an unhandled message.
- Got rid of the use of `children.foreach` as you already had a ref to the only child of that actor, so it seemed unnecessary to use this construct.  I would use that construct if you had a variable amount of children to send to and in this example you don't.

Comment: Thanks. But I do not understand this kind of line:

    case si @ SetInfluences(s0urce) => 
     influences ! si

Comment: @wipman, using the `@` symbol in a case statement lets you bind the thing after the `@` symbol to a variable using the thing that comes before the symbol as the variable name.  That way I don't have to recreate the the case class (like you were doing) if I want to simply propagate it to another actor (like I am doing via `!`).  It helps save in unnecessary object instance construction costs.  Check out the "variable binding" section of this link for more details: http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/case-classes-and-pattern-matching.html

Comment: .@ cmbaxter Big thanks for the tips and all! This helps me greatly!